# Laravel collection - filter() method setting custom property

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I made a custom collection class which extends laravel collection class. This custom collection has some data specific handeling methods and a property to make my life easier.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CustomCollection extends Collection
{
    public bool $myProperty = true;

    public function filterBasedOnCustomStuff()
    {
        return $this->filter(function ($row)
        {
            // Some custom sorcerry
            return ($var === "whatever");
        });
    }
}
```

And my question is. When I call `filterBasedOnCustomStuff()` method it returns a new CustomCollection object. Which is what I want of course. But I would also like to set the value of the `$myProperty` parametr of the new collection instance. Is it possible or I have to do that on the instance afterwards? Somethink like that:

```
$newCollection = $oldCollection->filterBasedOnCustomStuff();
$newCollection->myProperty = $oldCollection->myProperty;
```

I would like to avoid this aproach of setting it afterwards if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a variable to hold the filtered instance:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CustomCollection extends Collection
{
    public bool $myProperty = true;

    public function filterBasedOnCustomStuff()
    {
        $filtered = $this->filter(function ($row)
        {
            // Some custom sorcerry
            return ($var === "whatever");
        });

        $filtered->myProperty = $this->myProperty;

        return $filtered;
    }
}
```